# Error in file creation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to perform the following tasks with files, but I am stuck.

Here is the code:

```
NSString* aStr = @"Hello World!";

NSData* aData;
aData = [aStr dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//destination is NSString which Contains the absolute address

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destination]) 
{
      NSLog(@"File Exists!");
}
else
{
     BOOL statusOfFile=[fileManager createFileAtPath :destination contents:aData attributes:nil];
}

if(statusOfFile)
     printf("\n\nFile Created!");
else
     printf("\n\nError in File creation!");
```

---

I am not able to able to create a file - the value of `statusOfFile` is `NO`.

I tried this code in GNU and it works fine - the problem exists only with Xcode.

Can anybody tell me why?

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: You really like exclamation marks don't you?

Comment: That post needed some serious editing. The error still isn't terribly clear, though. :P

Comment: @socialCircus: Is there any reason you keep rolling back my edits? I'm try to help your question by fixing the code and making it more readable!

Comment: @socialCircus: Ok, so it seems to be accidental. (We were all editing at the same time.) No worries.

Comment: What's the filename you're trying to write to?

Comment: Is "destination" is within the iPhone sandbox?

Comment: to be clear: I was asking for the entire path. I agree with bdotdub, it sounds like you may be trying to write to a path you don't have permissions for.

Comment: Hi Ben,m trying to create a txt file in the resource folder of the project. is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that your destination is an invalid path on the iPhone. If you want to be able to write to a file in your apps sandboxed "Documents" folder, try this code:

```
+ (NSString *)dataFilePath {
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Filename.plist"];

  return filename;
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks alot @bdotdub but m trying to create a txt file .so if i change the extension will it work?

Comment: Yes, the parameter for stringByAppendingPathComponent can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

To access and store files on the iPhone I recommend reading [this](http://tinyurl.com/pkeu9m).

Erica Sadun has also written a nice [shorty](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/11/13/iphone-coding-use-nsbundle-and-avoid-hard-coded-paths/) about accessing file within a app bundle.